# Unknown [NONE] drained battery, now won't charge

Tags: laptop, battery

This morning my laptop's battery fully drained within 2 minutes and now will no longer charge, showing "0% available (plugged in)" in the taskbar.

I've run `powercfg /spr` and the report shows that 100% of the battery (2,029,070 mW) was drained in 0:01:51, and the power estimation shows 2,025,431 mW was used by "Unknown [NONE]" (the next highest only 1,594 mW).

I can unplug my laptop and it still works, although it goes into battery saver mode (I've tested for a few minutes before plugging back in).

I've tried reinstalling the Microsoft ACPI-Compliant Control Method Battery driver and power-resetting the laptop but neither has fixed the problem.

The laptop is a 15.6" PROTEUS V from pcspecialist.co.uk with an integrated battery running Windows 10.

Is there a solution to fix my issue?

Comment: Sounds like the battery is not calibrated anymore. Some UEFI BIOSes have a function for this, manually would mean: drain the battery until its completely empty, and keep powering on the laptop until the laptop won't turn on anymore, then while its turned off, fully charge the laptop. Turn on after 1 hour while plugged in to ensure its fully charge.

Comment: I left it powered off and unplugged overnight and this morning plugged it in and turned it on and immediately is says 86% and charging, so it definitely seems to be a calibration issue.